# Swapping text selections in Sublime Text 2

Tags: selection, sublimetext2

Forgive me if this has been asked before; I've looked around and while I can find (vague) documentation for swapping *lines* in Sublime Text, I can't see anything about swapping selections.

For instance, say I have the following text:

```
<div class="fade-black">...</div>
<div class="fade-white">...</div>
```

and I want to switch the colors of the two divs. So I select `black` and `white`. Now what? Is there anything built in, or should I be looking into writing an add-on myself? (I know that this particular example is relatively simple, but I have a lot of needs for this type of function in my code, and I can't simply swap lines because the content is not otherwise identical.)

Hopefully this helps some others out too -- definitely seems like a nice feature to know about!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To swap two (or more) selections you need to use the  **transpose** command, by default you can call it pressing **ctrl + t** (works on Sublime Text 3 too)

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+t"], "command": "transpose" }
```

Comment: Beautiful. Where have you been all my life?! :D

Comment: Love it. +1'd! :)

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in Joe's comment to Hugo's answer, you can swap two selections via the `Edit -> Permute Selections -> Reverse` menu item. **`Shuffle` won't always change the ordering as you want it to.**

You can map this operation to a key by adding something like this to your `Preferences -> Key Bindings – User` file, replacing `f8` with a [key binding](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) of your choice:

```json
{ "keys": ["f8"], "command": "permute_selection", "args": {"operation": "reverse"} },
```

Comment: See Ivan's answer below for an easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

Every day I'm shuffling...

Select both statements, Edit -> Permute Selections -> Shuffle.

Comment: Seems like reverse would be the better option in this case. Especially if there were more than 2 items selected.

Comment: The shuffle command doesn't guarantee an ordering change—shuffle enough times on two selections, and nothing will happen. As @JoeBergevin said, reversing is better.

Comment: Thank you -- even if enough shuffling gets you back to where you started, I never knew this feature existed, and I expect this to save me a ton of time in the future.